# LSTM Keras neural network representation

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I've came across the following code that generates an Sequential LSTM neural network with Keras and I wounder how would it be represented in therms of drawing.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(60, input_shape=(1, 6),
               activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(2))
```

If someone could explain it to me, that would be great!

Edit:
I'm looking for something like in this image: https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Keras-LSTM-tutorial-architecture.png

More specific: How would the input/output of the LSTM layer would look like and how would they be linked to the dense layer?

@Edit 2: I've made the following image: https://pasteboard.co/IEgqiVp.png
Would the neural network look like what I draw in the image, if I add the extra synaptic connections made by each input with each of the 60 neurons?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that runs in Google Colab, that can give you some information about the input and outputs:

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(60, input_shape=(1, 6),
               activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(2))

# write out model architecture
model.summary()

# Graphical plot
from IPython.display import SVG
from keras.utils import model_to_dot

iv1_dot = model_to_dot(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True, dpi=60)
SVG(iv1_dot.create(prog=['dot'], format='svg'))
```

In regard to the specific design, the LSTM layer has 60 nodes which are densely connected to the 2 final nodes.  That means that each of the 60 LSTM's are directly connected (with appropriate weights) to both of the final Dense nodes.  On the input side, you have defined a single time step with 6 features to the LSTM layer via the input_shape=(1,6).  So, the full input to the LSTM layer would look like:

(num_samples, num_timesteps, num_features)

where in this case, num_timesteps=1, num_features=6.  I believe, each feature then connects to each LSTM node.  Usually in keras, the num_samples is not directly specified in the network and appears as "None" in the architecture diagrams and summaries.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Would this neural network look **exactly** like this one? https://pasteboard.co/IEgqiVp.png (considering that in this image the x_i input is connected in one of 60 neurons and, since num_timesteps=1 each neuron unfolds one time, right?)

Comment: Read my "Edit 2", please.

Comment: @John Based on my understanding of the LSTM implementation, in your figure you should have 60 output nodes (which you call "h") and each input feature (x0 to x5) should densely connect to each LSTM node.  In other words, x0 should connect to all of the LSTM nodes, and x1 etc. likewise.  I believe that is what the implementation is doing.  You can further confirm this by examining the code on Keras github (LSTM is in the file: recurrent.py).  I hope this helps.